# There is a runtime error 91 on for loop

Tags: excel, vba

There is runtime error 91 on for loop need help!!

```
Sub clearSheet(WSName As String)

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Nothing

    With ActiveWorkbook
        Dim blWSExists As Boolean
        blWSExists = False
        For i = 1 To .Sheets.Count
            If .Sheets(i).Name = WSName Then
                blWSExists = True
                .Sheets(i).Activate
                .Sheets(i).Visible = xlSheetVisible
            End If
        Next
        If Not blWSExists Then
            Set ws = .Sheets.Add
            ws.Move after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
            ws.Name = WSName
            ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        End If
        .Sheets(WSName).AutoFilterMode = False
        .Sheets(WSName).Cells.Clear
        .Sheets(WSName).UsedRange.ClearOutline
        .Sheets(WSName).Cells.ClearFormats
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: try reversing the order of the 2 lines, first make it visible `.Sheets(i).Visible = xlSheetVisible` and then activate it `.Sheets(i).Activate`

Comment: nop did not work

Comment: Maybe it didn't, but you need to switch them anyway. at what line are you getting this error ?

Comment: you are trying to set ws twice. remove the second `Set`

Comment: The above code (edit 2) works fine for me. What line is highlighted when the error occurs?

Comment: For i = 1 To .Sheets.Count is highlighted when error occurs

Comment: Then your `With ActiveWorkbook` is not pointing where you think it's pointing.

Comment: maybe because you didn't declare i .. `Dim i As Long`

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim blWSExists As Boolean

blWSExists = False

For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name = WSName Then
        blWSExists = True
    End If
Next

If Not blWSExists Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = WSName
End If

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(WSName)

ws.AutoFilterMode = False
ws.Cells.Clear
ws.UsedRange.ClearOutline
ws.Cells.ClearFormats
ws.Activate
```

Comment: There is runtime error 1004 on this line :( "For Each ws In Worksheets"

Comment: @H.A Try put `Set ws = Nothing` before the For loop. This error is not occurring here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Cells.Delete()` to clear everything on a Worksheet:

```
Sub clearSheet(WSName As String)

    Dim s As Object

    For Each s in ThisWorkbook.Sheets  
        If s.Name = WSName Then
            s.Visible = xlSheetVisible
            If TypeOf s Is worksheet Then s.Cells.Delete    ' not all Sheets have cells, but all Worksheets do
            Exit Sub                                        ' to ignore the rest of the code if the Sheet exists
        End If
    Next

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)).Name = WSName

End Sub
```

or just delete the sheet and add new to clear absolutely everything associated with the sheet:

```
Sub clearSheet(WSName As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    Sheets(WSName).Delete
    Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = WSName 
End Sub
```